# How to prevent "Links from an external page" Showing links from specific domain?

Tags: backlinks, cpanel, awstats

I use inmotion hosting as my ISP. When I login to my CPANEL and open `Awstats`, I started seeing recently (about few month ago), the listing under **links from external page** filling up with all spam sites, but these all end up with `.fr/...` as the domain name.

If I click on one of these links to see why is it pointing to my site, ESET (my antivirus software on widows) blocks the connection and warns me of maleware.

These links are filling my listing now. All the sites end up with `.fr`

I will show below  a small list I copied. But please do not link to any of them. They have maleware !

```
       http://dpzv.christhecat.fr/....
       http://sqjh.erick-lenguin.fr/....
```

etc... There are literally dozens and dozens of these, filling almost 90% of the listing under **links from external page**

I tried the following: Editing my `.htaccess` file under `public_html/` and added the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*\.fr/ [NC,OR]
```

But it seems to have no effect. May be I did not write the above correctly? Is there something else to prevent domain ending with `.fr` from showing in this listing?

Is there something I can do? Should I contact in motion hostings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWStats has a mechanism to deal with this problem.  They have a [config directive called SkipReferrersBlackList](https://awstats.sourceforge.io/docs/awstats_config.html#SkipReferrersBlackList).

Create a .txt file with these referrers, each on its own line, then edit your AWStats config file to refer to that .txt file.  The referrers that are listed will then no longer appear in your reporting.